# Generalization of factorial based on the original combinatorial definition?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, factorial, gamma-function

I think I understand that factorial has been generalized using an approach wherein the function(s) evaluate to the normal definition of factorial for integers when applied to an integer but also can be applied to real numbers and even matrixes. What I am wondering is, does such a function continue to have anything to due with permutations so that this generalization yields something like the combinatorial definition for real numbers or is that false?

And if that is false, is there any example of trying to generalize the definition of permutation so that it does apply not just to integers but also real numbers, complex numbers and perhaps even matrixes?

I would also ask if the gamma function when applied to integers yields the number of permutations "by chance" or if there is some interpretation of the gamma function in which it is actually counting permutations?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question.  Is your question whether $\Gamma(z)$ has some sort of combinatorial interpretation for arbitrary complex numbers (*specifically non-integers*) or if it is purely an algebraic interpretation?  For that, we'd have to ask... *what counts as a purely combinatorial interpretation?*  The answer is likely no, but depending on how loosely you define things, it might be *maybe*.  As for "*is it 'by chance' that $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ for positive integers $n$?*"  The answer to that is very definitely... no it is by *design*.

Comment: Recall... definitions and special functions and such are generally *crafted* in such a way as to be useful to solve particular problems we want to solve or to be useful to describe things we want to describe.  The problems come first.  The definitions come afterwards.  The problem here was that we wanted a function like the factorial which satisfies certain nice properties but where our new function can also be used for arbitrary complex numbers.  We wanted it because it would be useful for describing solutions to various questions arising elsewhere like in calculus.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I think u understand my question. I do see it is by design that gamma(Int) == Int! but is there a way to look at gamma so that it is counting permutations? I mean, factorial is clearly counting specifically permutations so can we see this also about gamma? Further, I am asking if there is a function besides gamma that tries to extend the concept of permutations to objects that are not integers or does it make no sense to speak of this? i am thinking permutation might generalize to the number of parts of an object or objects of the same type that are smaller than the object itself.

Comment: The short answer is no.  The longer answer is that you need to be clearer what it is you are talking about.  As for "is there another function" yes, there are infinitely many, but the Gamma function is the most useful one as it is [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).

Comment: i guess irrespective of whether there is a function that works, what I am interested in is some sort of extension beyond integers for permutations. why should only integers have permutations? why can't there be a definition of permutation that is meaningful for complex numbers?

Comment: @JMoravitz: maybe this is related: https://oeis.org/wiki/Permutation_of_the_rational_numbers. But I also remain interested in showing that gamma is actually counting permutations for integers.